# How to show an AlertDialog after an await call in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

For some weird reason, I can't show an `AlertDialog` after an `await` call. The dialog just refused to show up. However, if I comment out the `await` call, the dialog shows.

```
void selectImage() async {
    var _fileName = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 250.0, maxHeight: 250.0);

showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => new AlertDialog(
      content: new Text("Random question?"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: const Text("NO")),
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: (() {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              setState(() {
                imageFile = _fileName;
              });
            }),
            child: const Text("YES"))
      ],
    ));

  }
```

Please, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of flutter are you on?  It is possible you are hitting this bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13818

Comment: @JonahWilliams Version  0.2.8

Comment: Could you temporarily switch to master and see if you still have the issue?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful if you post your entire widget class (I assume stateful widget?) - it's possible that you could be using `context` in a way that causes the problem, but we don't have enough context to figure it out from what you've posted. (see what I did there =D)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it seems working on the current Flutter version I'm using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void selectImage() async {
    var _fileName = await ImagePicker.platform.getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 250.0, maxHeight: 250.0);

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new AlertDialog(
        content: new Text("Random question?"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: const Text("NO")),
          new TextButton(
              onPressed: (() {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(
                  () {
                    var imageFile = _fileName;
                  },
                );
              }),
              child: const Text("YES"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: selectImage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

This is the version I'm using:

```
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (7 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
```